# Avoid Duplication when pushing object item into an Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an array of parking objects,
each parking has 4 floors and each floor has 10 spaces for cars

```
var parking = [
  {type:'car',plateNumber:'D555',parkingLevel:L1,parkingNumber:p1},
  {type:'car',plateNumber:'M225',parkingLevel:L2,parkingNumber:p9},
  {type:'car',plateNumber:'T765',parkingLevel:L2,parkingNumber:p2},
  {type:'car',plateNumber:'V366',parkingLevel:L4,parkingNumber:p3},
  {type:'car',plateNumber:'D121',parkingLevel:L1,parkingNumber:p5},
  {type:'car',plateNumber:'S909',parkingLevel:L3,parkingNumber:p1},
  {type:'car',plateNumber:'H551',parkingLevel:L4,parkingNumber:p5},
  {type:'car',plateNumber:'S305',parkingLevel:L3,parkingNumber:p1}
]
```

I want to be sure when we push new item to the parking array to **avoid duplicate** in the parkings
I mean we can not push p1 and p1 to L1

This is what I have tried:

```
$.each(parking, function (i, item) {
    var newCar = {
        level: car.parkingLevel,
        number: car.parkingNumber
    };
    var jsonFL = $.map(filterParking, function(v,i) {
        return JSON.stringify(v);
    });
    jsonFL.indexOf( JSON.stringify(newCar) ) > -1 || filterParking.push(newcar);
});
```

Comment: Why dont you just check whether the `newcar` object which you are going to insert is already present in the `parking` list before adding? Something like - `if($.inArray(newcar, parking) === -1){parking.push(newcar);}`

Comment: if i compare in this way i will never get true because anyway the cars plate numbers are different

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map for this.

```
var map = {}

// when pushing on the array
map[car.plateNumber] = car

// when removing a car
delete map[car.plateNumber]

// check if a car is parked
"undefined" !== typeof map["D555"]

// bonus: you can now get cars by plate number
map["D555"]  // {type:'car',plateNumber:'D555',parkingLevel:L1,parkingNumber:p1}
```

The underscore-solution adds an unnecessary dependency and could be slow depending on how often you add cars and how large your array grows.

Answer (score 0):

```
var parking = [
  {type:'car',plateNumber:'D555',parkingLevel:L1,parkingNumber:p1},
  {type:'car',plateNumber:'M225',parkingLevel:L2,parkingNumber:p9},
  {type:'car',plateNumber:'T765',parkingLevel:L2,parkingNumber:p2},
  {type:'car',plateNumber:'V366',parkingLevel:L4,parkingNumber:p3},
  {type:'car',plateNumber:'D121',parkingLevel:L1,parkingNumber:p5},
  {type:'car',plateNumber:'S909',parkingLevel:L3,parkingNumber:p1},
  {type:'car',plateNumber:'H551',parkingLevel:L4,parkingNumber:p5},
  {type:'car',plateNumber:'S305',parkingLevel:L3,parkingNumber:p1}
]


var newCar = {
  parkingLevel: car.parkingLevel,
  parkingNumber: car.parkingNumber
};

for(var i=parking.length-1; i>=0; i--){
  if(parking[i].parkingLevel === newCar.parkingLevel && parking[i].parkingNumber === newCar.parkingNumber)
    break;

  if(i === 0){
    parking.push(newCar);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether a car is already parked in the given slot before adding to the collection. Assuming `newcar` is the new car object you are trying to add, then:

```
var parkedCars = parking.filter(function(c){ return c.parkingLevel === newcar.parkingLevel && c.parkingNumber === newcar.parkingNumber });
if(parkedCars.length === 0){ //this means there isnt any car parked in that level and slot
  parking.push(newcar);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I used [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org) for this:

```
function containsObj(obj, objArray) {
   var obj= _.find(objArray, function(val){ return _.isEqual(obj, val);});
   return (_.isObject(obj))? true:false;
}
```

Just include library file and use this function.